# javascript not showing/hiding select box on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML/JS Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_col5" class="delete_col5" value="dragon_reseller" /> Delete<br>
        <select id="Customer_NewCallPlan5">
        <option value="">Change to...</option>
        </select>
        </td>       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input.delete_col5').on('click', function(){
                var trid = "Customer_NewCallPlan5";
                alert(trid);
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                     $('#' + trid).hide();
                }else{
                     $('#' + trid).show();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

it should show/hide the select box when the checkbox is checked/unchecked but it doesnt do anything.

i added the alert in to test but that doesnt even show anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can call the name directly in Jquery, you should use selector[name="name=delete_col5"],but to make it easier add an ID to your checkbox and select it with the # in jquery selector, then go on with your script.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="delete_col5" name="delete_col5" class="delete_col5" value="dragon_reseller" /> Delete<br>
        <select id="Customer_NewCallPlan5">
        <option value="">Change to...</option>
        </select>
        </td>       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#delete_col5').on('click', function(){
                var trid = "Customer_NewCallPlan5";
                alert(trid);
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                     $('#' + trid).hide();
                }else{
                     $('#' + trid).show();
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: You can call it by its name btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_col5" class="delete_col5" value="dragon_reseller" />     Delete<br>
    <select id="Customer_NewCallPlan5">
    <option value="">Change to...</option>
    </select>
    </td>       <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.delete_col5').change(function(){
            var trid = "Customer_NewCallPlan5";
            alert(trid);
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 $('#' + trid).hide();
            }else{
                 $('#' + trid).show();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works perfectly, it't just that you didn't accessed the input correctly. It is supposed to be :

```
$('input[name=delete_col5]')
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VWgWh/)**

And to make your function even easier, you could write it like this:

```
$('input[name=delete_col5]').on('click', function () {
  var trid = "#Customer_NewCallPlan5";
  $(trid).toggle();
});
```

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VWgWh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You should use "id" parameter instead of "name". In this way you can obtain it by #.
So your event will be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="delete_col5" name="delete_col5" class="delete_col5" value="dragon_reseller" /> Delete<br>

$('#delete_col5').on('click', function(){
...
...
});
```